# Foreach loop - performance with long string

Tags: c#, performance, foreach, base64

I'm facing a problem with performance in my C# application. The problem is a quite long string - base64 coded, but not ordinary. Even characters has to be moved 5 characters up and odd ones 5 characters down, to create a readable base64 string. Heres my code:

```
string b64stock; // <- long one
int b = 0;
string b64readable = "";
foreach (char c in b64Stock)
        {
            if ((b % 2) == 0)
            {
                int asciichar = (int)c;
                asciichar += 5;
                b64readable += (char)asciichar;
            }
            else
            {
                int asciichar = (int)c;
                asciichar -= 5;
                b64readable += (char)asciichar;
            }
            b++;
        }
```

I checked the code with stopwatch. It takes 17 seconds, to execute the loop. What steps should I take, to make this more efficient ?

Comment: How does adding and removing 5 to/from the ascii code make a base64 code string "readable"? o_O

Comment: @Jan Doerrenhaus - Its a sort of encryption. I receive it from network in this form, and i have to make the moving to make it convertable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` rather than a string:

```
string b64stock; // <- long one
int b = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b64Stock.Length);
foreach (char c in b64Stock)
{
    int asciiChar = (int)c;
    if ((b % 2) == 0)
    {
        asciichar += 5;
    }
    else
    {
        asciichar -= 5;
    }
    sb.Append((char)asciichar);
    b++;
}
string b64readable = sb.ToString();
```

The performance problem you're experiencing is because strings are immutable. When you write `myString += 'x'`, it doesn't modify `myString`. Rather, it creates a new string of the required length and copies the old `myString` to it. That kills performance even for relatively short strings.

The `StringBuilder` works as you expected the string to. Calling `Append` adds a character to the buffer, and the buffer is expanded automatically as needed. Although in this case it's not expanded at all because I pre-allocated it to the required length.

Comment: Now it takes 2 seconds. Thank you, Sir!

Comment: This will make a huge improvement in performance, there is a bit of room to tighten up the code in the loop, but that should not be needed and might be done for you by he compiler.